# Extract data from PHP array when a string value is given

Tags: php, arrays

I want to extract a information from a PHP array based on a given information.

Php is

```
$xmlstring = file_get_contents('http://www.bookingassist.ro/XML/test.xml');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
$HotelCodes[] = array('BG01I9', 'BG53I4', 'BG23I7');
$code = $HotelCodes[1];
if (!$code) {
   throw new Exception("No Hotel Code specified");
}
foreach ($HotelCodes as $code) {
  foreach ($hotels as $hotel) {
    if (strcasecmp($hotel['HotelCode'], $code) === 0) {
        echo "{$hotel['Latitude']}:{$hotel['Longitude']}<br/>";
        foreach ($hotel['HotelImages']['ImageUrl'] as $img) {
            echo "<img src='{$img}'/><hr/>";
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

`print_r $array`with one record is (the array has multiple records):

```
Array
( 
    [Hotel] => Array 
  ( 
[0] => Array ( 
     [HotelCode] => BG01I9 
     [Latitude] => 42.6039 
     [Longitude] => 23.3954 
     [HotelImages] => Array ( 
           [ImageURL] => Array ( 
                        [0] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/BG01I9/6481077_0x0.jpg 
                        [1] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/BG01I9/6481092_0x0.jpg 
                        [2] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/BG01I9/6481109_0x0.jpg 
                        [3] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/BG01I9/6481139_0x0.jpg 
                        [4] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/BG01I9/6481163_0x0.jpg 
                        [5] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/BG01I9/6480990_0x0.jpg 
                        [6] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/BG01I9/6481002_0x0.jpg 
                        [7] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/BG01I9/6481015_0x0.jpg 
                        [8] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/BG01I9/6481033_0x0.jpg 
                        [9] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/BG01I9/6481058_0x0.jpg 
   ) 
  ) 
 ) 
)
```

And i want to echo the Hotel Images, Latitude and Longitude based on the HotelCodes given by me:
The hotel code is `$HotelCodes[0]`

The error received is :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'No Hotel Code specified' in /home/truckass/public_html/site/test/teste.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/truckass/public_html/siteo/test/teste.php on line 10
```

I need to echo for `HotelCodes[1]`

```
$img[1][0] ....$img[1][5] 
$Latitude[1]
$Longitude[1]
```

Could you please assist.

Comment: Can you show any code?

Comment: @mc10 please check the question.

Comment: @segarci please check question.

Answer (score 0):

Loop array and check if `HotelCode` matches specified:

```
$HotelCodes = array('BG01I9', 'BG53I4', 'BG23I7');

if (!$code) {
   throw new Exception("No Hotel Code specified");
}

foreach ($HotelCodes as $code) {
  foreach ($hotels as $hotel) {
    if (strcasecmp($hotel['HotelCode'], $code) === 0) {
        echo "{$hotel['Latitude']}:{$hotel['Longitude']}<br/>";

        foreach ($hotel['HotelImages']['ImageUrl'] as $img) {
            echo "<img src='{$img}'/><hr/>";
        }

        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but how can i define the HotelCode, i dont understand. In my page HotelCode is defined by : $HotelCodes[0], $HotelCodes[1], $HotelCodes[2], ...... $HotelCodes[x]